# ASP.NET Core Web API over http

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application, which uses yarp. The application should be only a reverse proxy between outside word and other backend services.

I want to serve this application over http on localhost for development purposes, however, my request is always redirected to https endpoint. I'm using .NET 6.

I removed `UseHttpsRedirection()` but it didn't help. In logs, I see that application is served over `http://localhost:5000` and `https://localhost:5001`, but if I open `http://localhost:5000`, it is redirected to `https://localhost:5000` - what is wrong. In browser, I see `307 Internal Redirect` to `https://localhost:5000/`

I want to achieve that application is working over http and https as well on localhost.

This is my config:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var proxyBilder = builder.Services.AddReverseProxy();

proxyBilder.LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.MapGet("", () => $"It works! {string.Join(",", app.Urls)}");
app.MapReverseProxy();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.Run();
```

`launchsettings.json`:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Vocabulary.ServiceGateaway": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://+:5000"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "useSSL": false
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json"
}
```

Comment: Remove `app.UseHsts();` and it should work. This line basically forces the browser to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. See [Wikipedia - HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) for details.

Comment: It will not help as I'm on a Development environment. So !app.Environment.IsDevelopment() returns false. See the "!".

Comment: @Mushroomator you just helped me. It was a HSTS however not because of the application but because of the browser. I cleared the cache in the browser and it is working now.